# 'JsonParser' is abstract; cannot be instantiated 0

Tags: java, json, kafka-consumer-api, jsonparser

I'm trying to create a Kafka consumer in intellij but when I try to create the `JsonParser` it throws me an error :

> JsonParser is abstract; cannot be instantiated 0

```
private static JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser();

private static String extractIdFromTweet(String tweetJson){
   
    return jsonParser.parse(tweetJson)
            .getAsJsonObject()
            .get("id_str")
            .getAsString();
}
```

I have tried:

1. gson maven dependency
2. org.json.simple.JSONObject
3. org.json.JSONObject

but the error still persist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create [JsonParser](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/json/stream/JsonParser.html) using factory methods:

> The following example demonstrates how to create a parser from a string that contains an empty JSON array:

> ```
> JsonParser parser = Json.createParser(new StringReader("[]"));
> ```

> The class JsonParserFactory also contains methods to create JsonParser instances. JsonParserFactory is preferred when creating
> multiple parser instances. A sample usage is shown in the following
> example:
>
> ```
> JsonParserFactory factory = Json.createParserFactory();  
> JsonParser parser1 = factory.createParser(...);
> ```